# ListView load more on scroll bottom

Tags: android, listview, load, endlessadapter

In MainActivity I create the DownloadTask which populate model class then listview via CustomListAdapter class but I created the function to recognize end of scroll and I want to load more items to the listview. I was reading and looking at code on internet but I can't figure it out to solve this because its a kind different.
The MainActivity class

```
public void updateList() {
        adap = new CustomListAdapter(this, feedList, null);

         feedListView.setAdapter(adap);
         feedListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

             public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                     int scrollState) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 int threshold = 1;
                 int count = feedListView.getCount();

                 if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                     if (feedListView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
                             - threshold) {
                         mHandler = new Handler();
                         mIsLoading = true;


               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "END",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                 }
             }

             public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {


             }

         });


    }


     public class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

         @Override
         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                 if (null != feedList) {
                         updateList();
                 }

                 if (progressbar.isShown()) {
                  progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
                 }

         }

         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                 String url = params[0];

                 // getting JSON string from URL
                 JSONObject json = getJSONFromUrl(url);

                 //parsing json data
                 parseJson(json);
                 return null;
         }}
         public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
         InputStream is = null;
         JSONObject jObj = null;
         String json = null;

         // Making HTTP request
         try {
                 // defaultHttpClient
                 DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                 HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                 HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                 is = httpEntity.getContent();

                 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                 is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                 String line = null;
                 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                         sb.append(line + "\n");
                 }
                 is.close();
                 json = sb.toString();
         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         }

         try {
                 jObj = new JSONObject(json);
         } catch (JSONException e) {
                 Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
         }

         // return JSON String
         return jObj;

   }

   public void parseJson(JSONObject json) {
         try {

                 // parsing json object
                 if (json.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                         JSONArray posts = json.getJSONArray("posts");




                         feedList = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

                         for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {

                                 JSONObject post = (JSONObject) posts.getJSONObject(i);
                                 FeedItem item = new FeedItem();

                                /////.....  
                                 feedList.add(item); 



                         }

                         } 



         } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         }
   }
```

CustomListAdapter

```
 public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  
{



    private int mCount = 25;
    private ArrayList<FeedItem> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> data;
    protected ListView feedListView;

    public CustomListAdapter( Context context, ArrayList<FeedItem> listData)
    { 


        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mContext = context;

    }

    public void addMoreItems(int count) {
        mCount += count;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }


    public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
     final ViewHolder holder;
     View row=convertView;
        if ((row == null) || (row.getTag()==null)) {

         convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
         holder = new ViewHolder();
      ////
         convertView.setTag(holder);






        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

       final FeedItem newsItem = (FeedItem) listData.get(position);
      /////



        return convertView;
    }


static class ViewHolder
    {
        ////
    }


}
```

When I reach the bottom the toast is created.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using OnScrollListener, you can compare position to list data size and load more items accordingly within your adapter class.

```
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
  if(position == getCount()-1){
     // load new items here. you can do a for loop here, if you'd like to add multiple items.
     addMoreItems(newItem);
  }

  // rest of the getView implementation
}
```

And you also need to update the following methods:

```
public void addMoreItems(FeedItem newItem) {
   listData.add(newItem); // since you want to add this item at the end of the list
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
   return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position){
    return listData.get(position);
}
```

And don't create a new adapter when you want to update your listView, like you did in your update method. If you do that, it'll get rid of the previous content. Instead, just call addMoreItems method of your adapter, it'll do the trick for you.

Comment: Can you give me the example? I am new to Android so i dont know the best way to do

Comment: I edited my answer and added a sample/pseudo code. Let me know if it's not clear enough.

Comment: But how can i add NewData? As you seen i limited the items by private int mCount = 25; in Adapter

Comment: Oh I overlooked that, you shouldn't limit the count. You can just get rid of that and return listData.size() in getCount() method.

Comment: What should i do with newItem in addMoreItems(newItem) because  newItem cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: but where is the limit now? I want to limit on 25 items and them load 25 more

Comment: You should use a limit before passing the listData to the adapter. You can create an arraylist with 25 items initially, pass that to the adapter and add 25 more items whenever the user reaches to the end of the list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44912/discussion-between-ayorhan-and-sandra-mladenovic)

Comment: Hey looks good, but does something need to happen for caching, picasso is already dealing with my picture caching but what about the text? if a user scrolls 200 items down for example

Comment: Also, if the list runs out of items can it lead to a problem, or does something need to be added? Because I am assuming it will try to load when it cant

Answer (score 1):

```
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(scrollState==RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){

                  visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                  totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                  firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();


                  if (loading) {
                   if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    loading = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                   }
                  }

                  if (!loading  && (totalItemCount - visibleThreshold) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount)) {

                      Log.v("scroll","Last Item Wow !");

                      if(footerView.getVisibility()!=View.VISIBLE){
                          footerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      }

                        refreshExpListViewData();
                  }
            }

        }
```

Comment: private  LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
 private int previousTotal = 0;
  private boolean loading = true;
  private int visibleThreshold = 5;
  int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to implement "endless scrolling" is to use the `EndlessAdapter` library by commonsguy.

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless